# How do I Delete Documents I uploaded to CiviEvent?

Tags: civievent, custom-fields

We've uploaded hundreds of documents over the past few years - under the event module (schedules, programs, etc.) - how do we access and delete them now? I can't locate where they are stored.

Comment: Hi - thank you for your answer. I went to the URL - but can't get to the actual "files" that are stored there. I apologize that don't have a lot of technical expertise. Any additional guidance appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Win - sorry didn't notice your comment until just now. I just added some something to my answer - does that help?

Comment: Excellent - if you think this is answered - please mark it as such - to keep SE happy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go here:

```
/civicrm/admin/setting/path?reset=1
```

to find out what the Custom Files Directory is for your instance!

Custom Files Directory:
"Path where documents and images which are attachments to contact records are stored (e.g. contact photos, resumes, contracts, etc.). These attachments are defined using 'file' type custom fields."

ADDED: You'll need access to your server - eg through eg CPanel FileManager - or those who like and have command line access can SSH to their server and then navigate to the custom files directory.